# ManyToManyField does not show

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Want to use REST API to populate my tables but my field does not display on the API page.

Models (Series, Roster):

```
class Series(models.Model):
    (...)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Roster(models.Model):
    (...)
    series = models.ManyToManyField(Series)
    (...)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializers:

```
class SeriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Series
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'icon')
        read_only_fields = ('slug',)

class RosterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    series = SeriesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Roster
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'number', 'primary_color', 'secondary_color', 'image', 'series')
```

Views:

```
class SeriesView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SeriesSerializer
    queryset = Series.objects.all()

class RosterView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = RosterSerializer
    queryset = Roster.objects.all()
```

Unsure where I am mistepping here.

Comment: Can you show any sample data?

Comment: I actually found out what the issue it a couple minutes ago, I just need to update.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that all I needed to do was remove

`series = SeriesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)`

and adjust my `series` field to

`series = models.ForeignKey(Series, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)`

No idea why this ended up working though so an explanation would still be cool.